# ¿Cómo eliminar la llamada a un archivo .css de Font-Awesome el cual no existe?

Tags: css, wordpress, font-awesome

Mi web tarda en cargar 1 segundo más por un archivo que supuestamente no está en mi servidor `https://midominio/path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`.

¿Cómo podría eliminar esta llamada?

He entrado en todos los archivos de mi theme (Airi WordPress Theme) y no encuentro dicha llamada a esa librería.

¿Alguien podría orientarme un poco?

De antemano, muchas gracias

[image]

Comment: Prueba a hacer una búsqueda de archivos que contengan el texto "font-awesome.min.css" en la carpeta del proyecto.
Si no lo encuentra debe ser código que se descarga. Siempre puedes crear un archivo dummy...

Comment: ¿Te refieres a hacer una búsqueda en mi hosting? ¡Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: En wordpress en ajustes hay una opción para editar archivos del tema. Lo normal es que en los archivos del header encuentres todos los meta del tema y seguramente esté esa llamada.

Comment: Sii, es lo que yo he pensado, pero no he encontrado nada ... Voy a mirar de nuevo, quizá hay algún archivo que se inserta en el header.php y se me ha pasado. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Me refería a una búsqueda local, entiendo que puedes descargarte todos los archivos.

Comment: ¿Y cómo puedo hacer una búsqueda de una cadena de texto entre múltiples archivos? Disculpa las molestias y gracias de antemano!

Comment: Busca en el fronted ese archivo, cuando lo encuentres deberia estar asociado a un ID, usa ese Id con la funcion wp_dequeue_style() mas el id para remover el archivo del fronted

Comment: `$ grep -nir 'awesome'`